# PHP application not saving data to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am creating my first Wordpress plugin and have been stumped for a couple of days. So far I am trying to just get my plugin to save data to the MySQL database on my localhost. When I enter info into the form it creates a new row, which auto increments, but does not pass any of the info that I have entered into the database.

I understand that I have to clean up a lot of this code before I use it but I am just starting and stumped on this particular issue. 
Here is the relevant code;

dvi_customer_info.php file

```
<?php



 require('database.php');
 require('customer_info_functions.php');


if ($action == 'add_customer') {
$rep = $_POST['rep'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];




}
 add_customer($rep, $business, $address, $phone, $name, $email);

    include('dvi_customer_info_sheet.php');
```

customer_info_functions.php file

```
<?php

function add_customer($rep, $business, $address, $phone, $name, $email) {
global $db;
$query = "INSERT INTO customers
             (repName, customerBusiness, customerAddress, customerPhone, customerName, customerEmail)
          VALUES
             ('$rep', '$business', '$address', '$phone', '$name', '$email')";
$db->exec($query);
}
?>
```

dvi_customer_info_sheet.php file

```
<body>
<h1>Customer Info Sheet</h1>
<form action="dvi_customer_info.php" method="post"       id="customer_info_sheet_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_customer" />

    <label>Name of Rep:</label>
    <input type="input" name="rep" />
    <br />

    <label>Name of Business:</label>
    <input type="input" name="business" />
    <br />

    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="input" name="address" />
    <br />

    <label>Phone #:</label>
    <input type="input" name="phone" />
    <br />

    <label>Name of Decision Maker:</label>
    <input type="input" name="name" />
    <br />

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="input" name="email" />
    <br />


    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Customer" />
    <br />  <br />
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: I am not clear About your if condition if($action =='add_customer' ) instead of that try if(isset($_POST['add_customer']))

What is $action?

Answer (score 0):

```
 "INSERT INTO customers
         (repName, customerBusiness, customerAddress, customerPhone, customerName, customerEmail)
      VALUES
         (\"$rep\", $business,...)
```

(Use double quotes "$rep" or don't use any quotes $business ( use this option) as anything within single quotes is taken as it is i.e a string constant and hence the variable inside that didn't get substituted by it's value

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers
         (repName, customerBusiness, customerAddress, customerPhone, customerName, customerEmail)
      VALUES
         ('".$rep."', '".$business."', '".$address."', '".$phone."', '".$name."', '".$email."')";
```

And Also

I am not clear About your if condition if($action =='add_customer' ) instead of that try

```
if(isset($_POST['add_customer']))
```

What is $action?

Answer (score 0):

you can use wordpress default action to insert record in to database like this below code it's sure to insert your record in mysql database.

You have no need to use function to just insert record in database just put this code in `dvi_customer_info.php` file

```
<?php
    require('database.php');
    require('customer_info_functions.php');
    global $wpdb;
    if ($action == 'add_customer') {
        $rep = $_POST['rep'];
        $business = $_POST['business'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];



        $your_table_name_here = $wpdb->prefix . 'yourdatanase_table';
        $data = array(
                    'repName' => $rep,
                    'customerBusiness' => $business,
                    'customerAddress' => $address,
                    'customerPhone' => $phone,
                    'customerName' => $name,
                    'customerEmail' => $email
                    );
        $idsa = $wpdb->insert($your_table_name_here, $data);
        if ($idsa) {
            echo '<p class="alert-box success tfamsg">Franchise Setting Inserted.</p>';
        }

    }
    include('dvi_customer_info_sheet.php');
?>
```

Now it will insert record in database you had also change your database table `$your_table_name_here`.

Thanks